# Prevent moveend event being fired in Leaflet after setView

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I have a simple question that has me stumped:

In a Leaflet application, I have an event listener for clicking elements on the map:

```
marker.on('click', function () {
            doStuff();
            $('element').doStuff();
            setView(this.getLatLng());
        });
```

However, the setView method also triggers a 'map moved' event, which I do not want to fire. Using either plain JavaScript or jQuery, can I prevent any other event from firing while inside the click event function?

Edit: now with a Fiddle! To use it, just click anywhere on the map. As you can see, e.stopPropagation() does not work when placed inside the click event listener.

http://jsfiddle.net/gc6e4jbg/

Comment: can you show the setView function

Comment: For this you need to modify setView as setView space is outside click event.

Comment: The setView function is a standard Leaflet function, and I would prefer not to edit the library itself. I posted a JSFiddle for your perusal.

Comment: e.stopPropagation only works for the e (event) that you are calling it on. What you will need to do is write some custom functionality (extending the library may be best) or refactor your code - why are you using both **click** and **mouseend** for this particular element? Do you need to be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe you can prevent `moveend` being fired. (NB: these aren't jQuery events - Leaflet has its own internal event system.) This is the source for `setView`:

```
setView: function (center, zoom) {
    zoom = zoom === undefined ? this.getZoom() : zoom;
    this._resetView(L.latLng(center), this._limitZoom(zoom));
    return this;
}
```

`_resetView` always fires `moveend` at the end:

```
_resetView: function (center, zoom, preserveMapOffset, afterZoomAnim) {
    var zoomChanged = (this._zoom !== zoom);
    if (!afterZoomAnim) {
        this.fire('movestart');
        if (zoomChanged) {
            this.fire('zoomstart');
        }
    }

    ...

    this.fire('moveend', {hard: !preserveMapOffset});
}
```

You could investigate customizing these functions to allow for suppression of the event.

**Update:**

Alternatively, you could change your `moveend` event handler. Have it track a flag, which you set when you don't want the normal operations to happen.

For example, you'll have set up your handler similar to:

```
map.on('moveend', myHandler);
```

Have `myHandler` do something like:

```
function myHandler(e) {
    if (stopFlag) {
        return;
    }
    else {
        // Normal operation
        ...
    }
}
```

Then just enable and disable `stopFlag` to control the flow. The advantage of this is that you don't have to publish a custom version of Leaflet with your application.

Comment: @Baz - added a possible alternative above, which should be easier to implement.

Comment: This was the cleanest solution I could think of as well, so thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To be straight to the point: that will never work. By using `stopPropagation`/`preventDefault` you stop the `click` event from bubbling up through the dom. Nothing else. Once you execute `L.Map`'s `setView` method it will always fire the `moveend` event, it's got nothing to do with the `click` event. It will also the fire `movestart` and `move` events and even the `resetview` event if you also set the zoomlevel in `setView`. That's just the way Leaflet works. You could always extend `L.Map` to write you own logic but i'm guessing you're better of finding another solution to your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I will have to take your advice and choose between custom logic and a different solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my a bit more hackish solution.

### At the beginning

Set moveend to `true` as a default value.

```js
var moveend = true;
```

### Inside a click event

Set moveend to `false`.

```js
moveend = false;
map.setView(new L.LatLng(lat, lng));
```

### moveend event

Do something if `moveend` is `true`. No matter what, set `moveend` to `true` for next run.

```js
map.on('moveend', (e) => {
  if (moveend) {
    // Do something if moveend is enabled
  }
  moveend = true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use event.stopPropagation(), [see the docs](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

```
marker.on('click', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
}
```

Comment: This doesn’t work per https://stackoverflow.com/a/28189658/735926